# Is the statement always true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$ belong to a vector space V over the real numbers $\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}\Bbb R$.

Is the statement $\sp\{ \vec{u} , \vec{v} , \vec{w} \} = \sp\{ \vec{u} ,\vec{u} + \vec{v}, \vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w} \}$ always true?

I'am having trouble with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is <$\vec{u}$ , $\vec{v}$ , $\vec{w}$>?

Comment: Likely the span of $\{ u, v, w \}$, but yeah it's unclear.

Comment: yep it is span of   $\{u,v,w\}$  . I edited my post . Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=\alpha u+\beta v+\gamma w\in\mathrm{span}\{u,v,w\}$, then
$$
x=(\alpha-\beta) u+(\beta-\gamma)(u+v)+\gamma(u+v+w)\in\mathrm{span}\{u,u+v,u+v+w\}.
$$
Hence $\mathrm{span}\{u,v,w\}\subset\mathrm{span}\{u,u+v,u+v+w\}$. The reversed inclusion is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

span$\{u,v,w \}$ is equal to span$\{u, u+v, u+v+w\}$ if it is possible to write each of the three vectors $u,v,w $ in terms of the new vectors $u, x=u+v, y=u+v+w$, since obviously, $u, u+v, u+v+w$ are written in terms of $u,v,w$.
we have :
$$u=u$$
$$v=u+v-u=x-u$$
$$w=u+v+w-u-v=y-x$$
hence span$\{u,v,w \}$=span$\{u, u+v, u+v+w\}$